# How to generate and display links from PHP array using "WHERE"

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array of categories like this

```
$category = array(
    1 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'parentID' => 0,
        'name' => 'SUV auto parts'
    ),
        2 => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'parentID' => 1,
            'name' => 'Engine Related'
        ),
            3 => array(
                'id' => 3,
                'parentID' => 2,
                'name' => 'Spark Plugs'
                        ),
            4 => array(
                'id' => 4,
                'parentID' => 2,
                'name' => 'Engine Oil'
                        ),
        5 => array(
            'id' => 5,
            'parentID' => 1,
            'name' => 'Body related'
        ),
    6 => array(
        'id' => 6,
        'parentID' => 0,
        'name' => 'Sedan auto parts'
    ),
        7 => array(
            'id' => 7,
            'parentID' => 6,
            'name' => 'Engine Related'
            ),
        );
```

I have no idea how to get this done just by using PHP array without MYSQL query,
trying to display sub-categories where 'parentID' = supplied category ID

for example when category id 1 is requested, I wanna list name and html link for category 2 and 5,
when category id 2 is requested, I wanna display name and html link for category 3 and 4

---

**SUV auto parts**

Sub-categories; [*Spark Plugs*](/category.php?id=3)  [*Engine Oil*](/category.php?id=4)

---

likewise when "Engine Related" page is requested

---

**Engine Related**

Sub-categories; [*Engine Related*](/category.php?id=2)  [*Body related*](/category.php?id=5)

---

I appreciate if someone will give any solution.

Comment: So iterate over your array and find records that you need. What's the __exact__ problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More sophisticated approaches exist surely, but a solution that is easy to understand and tailor(e.g. prettify) to your use case, is the following:

```
$parentId = 2; // set the parentID

foreach($category as $key => $value) {
    if($value['parentID'] == $parentId) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($value); // print matching record
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/TUhvX)